# Why don't we take humanity and push it somewhere with lower entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, universe, biology

Entropy increases overtime, which will eventually lead to the heat death of the universe. Surely though, there is somewhere in the universe with lower entropy then where we are know, given that, according to current theories, the universe is infinite. We could colonize that region. When that region nears the heat death, we can move somewhere else, ad infinitum.

On average, how far we have to go to avoid the heat death?

Comment: Freeman Dyson's classic paper '[Time without end: Physics and biology in an open universe](https://blog.regehr.org/extra_files/dyson.pdf)' explores a version of this question that applies to a ballistic non-closed universe. Alas it's optimistic conclusions are not sustainable in a universe dominated by dark energy.

Comment: Why don't we? Because we can't :)

Comment: Don't worry about the heat death. There is a plan to terminate 95% of the world population much sooner:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_Guidestones#Inscriptions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a question about the survival of humanity, and not a question about physics. The final question could be about physics if *avoiding heat death* was given a physical criterion.

Answer (score 3):

To survive, we need to maintain our own low entropy state. This is most readily done by being open systems: we take free energy from our environment and use it to reduce our entropy, dumping it as waste heat in the environment. This works well right now since we have the sun (and radioisotopes) that produce a temperature differential relative to the cosmic background temperature. The problem is that over time we will run out of such temperature differences allowing us to maintain ourselves since we are irreversibly using up the mass-energy we can access.

As dmckee mentioned, there are theoretical ways around it. Freeman Dyson started the field of "[physical eschatology](https://arxiv.org/ftp/astro-ph/papers/0211/0211413.pdf)" with his [1979 paper](https://blog.regehr.org/extra_files/dyson.pdf). There he examined under what cosmological conditions life could persist. In an open universe temperatures decline forever, so if life uses energy at an ever slower rate it goes much further: the value of energy is in a sense inversely proportional to temperature, and this can in principle lead to indefinite survival.

But [there are problems with this given what we know about our universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9902189). The accelerating expansion of the universe means that there is only a finite amount of matter available to us (the rest, beyond our future light-cone, can never be collected even though we can see it). In the right cosmology this might still be OK. But there is an extra catch: there will be a finite horizon temperature (similar to the Hawking temperature of a black hole event horizon) of about $10^{-29}$ Kelvin. This means that one will never get arbitrarily low temperatures, and hence there is a limit on the number of "life operations" we can do with our finite endowment of mass-energy. [We can still maximise it by using it in the late era when the horizon temperature dominates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03394), but it is finite.

If there had not been a limit on how far we could travel, then there would in principle have existed a way to survive indefinitely in a spatially infinite universe. Even though most places we can see are at roughly the same level of temperature and entropy, by sheer chance there would be other regions that had lower entropy and better energy gradients. In an infinite universe there would always be such spots. The problem is that the distances in time and space are beyond astronomical. Roughly, the expected distance to a region of reduced entropy grows exponentially with its space-time volume, and this places it beyond the observable universe (so we do not where to go) and likely in a extremely far future time (so we do not survive the wait).

Fixing the heat death of the universe is kind of [the ultimate question](https://www.physics.princeton.edu/ph115/LQ.pdf). It looks hard at present, but there is plenty of time left.